# df is omitting some whole parts of my fs / disks. Is there something wrong?

Tags: mount, filesystem, df

EDIT(2015-03-08): I think this behaviour is caused by ubuntu-sdk using schroot and overlayfs to install its dev kits. See https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt and https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/sdk/tutorials/building-cross-architecture-click-applications/

I have a laptop with two physical disks, ~1TB each.

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ blkid 
/dev/sda3: UUID="waaa02-V9C4-YPqM-C6vu-wpAd-QwPe-6JDrCS" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="e7e30cb9-1358-49b6-a991-9000fa32be70" 
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo blkid
Swipe your right index finger across the fingerprint reader
/dev/sda3: UUID="waaa02-V9C4-YPqM-C6vu-wpAd-QwPe-6JDrCS" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="e7e30cb9-1358-49b6-a991-9000fa32be70" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="B7ED-D7E9" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="5c17a74c-706e-4d2a-bb04-3157900ef3f6" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="f4ce6839-ce59-4d7f-a106-e04c06bc0c03" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="610befd8-d98d-4306-acfe-d5aca7375a46" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="data" UUID="82dc2f8e-91b9-4d96-8e80-01bb8139300c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d2bcce3b-0303-417b-b1a5-64054694f156" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--root: UUID="76224107-a31a-4a71-b115-926e0eec320d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--var: UUID="9ae852a7-68d6-45f0-acc5-ffb6eee62ccc" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--home: UUID="23b1c628-0b78-47bb-bba0-1cf694fcdb9d" TYPE="ext4"
```

(notice the difference when using sudo... don't know if it's meaningful)

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ ll /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 400 Mar  6 09:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Mar  6 09:01 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar  6 09:01 ata-Crucial_CT1024M550SSD1_14110C0AFD52 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 ata-Crucial_CT1024M550SSD1_14110C0AFD52-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 ata-Crucial_CT1024M550SSD1_14110C0AFD52-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 ata-Crucial_CT1024M550SSD1_14110C0AFD52-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar  6 09:01 ata-Samsung_SSD_840_EVO_1TB_mSATA_S1KRNEAF300981W -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 ata-Samsung_SSD_840_EVO_1TB_mSATA_S1KRNEAF300981W-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-lv--home -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-lv--root -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-lv--var -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 dm-uuid-LVM-jBidHcOmS5PLgOnIfgfWxcu35IHAc3oA3XgOAXUIncgAvTG973Lh4L5Hp3RTv6WC -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 dm-uuid-LVM-jBidHcOmS5PLgOnIfgfWxcu35IHAc3oADK8PIqDaAIz6E4rqHiPhf2Xjl0RxEfBO -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 dm-uuid-LVM-jBidHcOmS5PLgOnIfgfWxcu35IHAc3oAKyrRw58kYqKSjMuTY0LJqVl6WHunWt0Y -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar  6 09:01 wwn-0x5002538844584d30 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 wwn-0x5002538844584d30-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar  6 09:01 wwn-0x500a07510c0afd52 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 wwn-0x500a07510c0afd52-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 wwn-0x500a07510c0afd52-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar  6 09:01 wwn-0x500a07510c0afd52-part3 -> ../../sda3
```

There are mounted this way:

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# ...
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--root /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f4ce6839-ce59-4d7f-a106-e04c06bc0c03 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=B7ED-D7E9  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--home /home           ext4    noatime,defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--var /var            ext4    noatime,defaults        0       2
#
UUID=82dc2f8e-91b9-4d96-8e80-01bb8139300c /srv/mm       ext4    noatime,defaults    0   2
#
# /tmp in ram to preserve SSDs
tmpfs      /tmp          tmpfs      defaults,mode=1777    0    0
```

**But** I'm having only partial output from df comand above. Notice that /home and /var mount points do not appear anywhere. And indeed, a full disk is almost missing in this output.

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--root                        19G  7.9G  9.9G  45% /
none                                                  4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev                                                  7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/dev
/tmp                                                  7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/tmp
tmpfs                                                 1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
none                                                  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/run/shm                                              7.8G  496K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/run/shm
none                                                  100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2                                             985M  224M  712M  24% /boot
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386   28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1
/dev/sdb1                                             874G  570G  260G  69% /srv/mm
/dev/sda1                                             511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64                           28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64                           28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf                           28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf                           28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386                            28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386                            28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9
```

But the mount command give me another story:

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ mount | grep vg
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--home on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--var on /var type ext4 (rw,noatime)
```

(plus a full bunch of things I stripped for readability)

Why is df so confused ? Is there something wrong with my fs ? And how do these /var/lib/schroot/chroots/ mount point work ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT1: issuing df -h -a gives me a more complete but strange (to me) result...

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ df -h -a
Filesystem                                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--root                         19G  7.9G  9.9G  45% /
proc                                                      -     -     -    - /proc
sysfs                                                     -     -     -    - /sys
none                                                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                                      0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none                                                      0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none                                                      0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
none                                                      0     0     0    - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
udev                                                      -     -     -    - /dev
devpts                                                    -     -     -    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                                                     -     -     -    - /tmp
tmpfs                                                  1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
none                                                   5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none                                                      -     -     -    - /run/shm
none                                                   100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user
none                                                      0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
/dev/sda2                                              985M  224M  712M  24% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--home                           -     -     -    - /home
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--var                            -     -     -    - /var
/dev/sdb1                                              874G  570G  260G  69% /srv/mm
/dev/sda1                                              511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
binfmt_misc                                               0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
systemd                                                   0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64     -     -     -    - /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64                            28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-2c10adb7-7c2d-44dd-b455-39e5b396dbb9/run/shm
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64     -     -     -    - /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64                            28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64-6cdf130c-c5ed-4261-826f-0f1e8355b087/run/shm
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf     -     -     -    - /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf                            28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-396914cd-21f7-46ca-98ca-5c297c88be1a/run/shm
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf     -     -     -    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-68af14d0-808d-4ef8-9f7b-5c8199937096/run/shm
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf     -     -     -    - /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf                            28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-dca33aeb-316b-414b-ac88-7694565bfaac/run/shm
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386    28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386                             28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-2ce339c6-bce3-4a5e-8c60-06722a0f4bb1/run/shm
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386    28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9
click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386                             28G   23G  4.0G  86% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9
/proc                                                     0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/proc
/sys                                                      0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/sys
/dev                                                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/dev
/dev/pts                                                  0     0     0    - /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/dev/pts
/home                                                  891G  218G  629G  26% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/home
/tmp                                                   7.8G  2.1M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/tmp
/run/shm                                               7.8G  504K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386-5d7eb656-e0cf-4e22-a37e-a82d90152de9/run/shm
gvfsd-fuse                                                0     0     0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

Comment: well, you can read the man pages for mount and df. I think your output looks normal, so what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @j0h I will edit my question if it's not clear: the problem is that df is omitting some whole parts of my fs / disks. Especially, /home is mounted on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--home but is not listed in df output. Same goes for /var.

Comment: /var isn't listed in my df -h.  but, your output does look like df -h -a

Comment: df -h -a gives me a huge output, where /home and /var appear, but with blank size / used / avail. columns... I'm under the impression that /home and /var mountpoints from the chroots somehow interfere with my real /home and /var...

Comment: could you add in the contents of your /etc/fstab and the list of /dev/disk/by-id this will help us determine what the output of df is showing. Also check the output from a sudo df. If there is any difference to the outputs (unlikely) then please update your post. You've just added in the df-h-a which does give a lot of info. as you say this seems to be somehow related to the 'ubuntu-click' partitions, which all seem to be parked on /var/lib. I'm not up to speed on these partitions. Can you give some info regarding your setup to help me understand, also the fstab may help. cheers

Comment: Do you develop and cross-compile for arm, 32-bit and 64-bit Intel?

Comment: @Fabby no I don't really... in fact I have pure QML/js app, so I think it's pretty arch agnostic, but I indeed created those kits, trying to understand how the sdk was working...

Comment: OK, I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question then???* :/

Comment: @Fabby in fact I was lost as 'df -h' was giving me stange results (esp. a whole disk was missing). But it turned out that it was due to cross-compile kits using overlayfs / unionfs. Then I edited the question, and maybe it's unclear now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `df --human` combined with the `--all` is absolutely normal for the system you have, looking at the packages you installed.

So you can *stop worrying*!  ;-)

Comment: Cool :-) I'm glad it helped me sort out my system a bit ! Thanks